# undo commit in merged branch

Tags: git

Commit graph (how it is):

```
* hash1 - (HEAD) last commit
* hash2 - merge commit
|\
| * hash3 - last branch commit that should be undone
| * hash4 - this commit should have been merged instead of hash3
| * hash5 - first branch commit
* | hash6 - commit on master after branch creation
|/
* hash7 - before trouble began
...
```

Commit `hash4` is the last working commit, but is on a different branch (not master). `hash3` is a bad commit that breaks the project, but is merged with master (`hash2`). `hash1` is an unsuccessful try to fix. How can I revert to `hash4` and merge with `hash6` to get a working project again?

Commit graph (how it should be):

```
* hash2 - merge commit
|\
| * hash4 - this commit should have been merged instead of hash3
| * hash5 - first branch commit
* | hash6 - commit on master after branch creation
|/
* hash7 - before trouble began
...
```

Comment: For this simple case move the branch head to #hash6 and merge in #hash4. The previous head/branch will then be 'abandoned'.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

#### **`git reflog`**

reflog store history of every change that was made to the `HEAD`. You can checkout your repository to any given commit (detached HEAD), create branch from that point and do your stuff.

for example:

```
git reflog
.. find out the HEAD@{n} of your desired commit
git checkout HEAD@{n}
git checkout -b my_new_branch
// At this point you have new branch with **head4** as your last commit
```

---

#### **`git revert`**

git revert lets you "rollback" = revert  commit(s) that you wish to discard.

```
git revert SHA1 SHA1 SHA1 SHA1

git revert head3
```

This will create a commit with the undo of the changes made in head3